Is this uniform Boer War?
This photo has been enhanced as the original is very damaged. I’ve been told it is my Great Grandfather who joined up to fight in the 2nd Boer War when under age. He was born and bred on London but the hat looks like it may be Scottish. I have no other contemporary photos of him so can’t confirm it is him. He also fought in WW1 but have no details of campaigns but he did survive.


The London Scottish Regiment served in the Boer War.  Memorial here https://www.iwm.org.uk/memorials/item/memorial/2866# Uniform shown is about he right vintage.
